# Increasing efficiency of a large lottery simulation

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I created a python lottery simulator that generates an array of 5 random numbers from 0-75 (the 'winning numbers'):

```
    for n in xrange(0, 5):
    winning_number.append(randint(0, 75))
```

It would then check a user-defined number of 'tickets' (the 'count' variable) against the 'winning' array.

```
while count > 0:
    for n in xrange(0, 5):
        result.append(randint(0, 75))
    if result == winning_number:
        wingame += 1
        count -= 1
        del result[:]
    else:
        count -= 1
        del result[:]
```

As expected, count values above about 10 million start to take a long time and begin to tax my system resources, but I  really want to run much larger values of count. Are there any modifications that I could make to help avoid superfluous steps? Also, would using something like PyCUDA or pyOpenCl be effective and/or within the reach of someone pretty new to coding?

I appreciate any help that you can provide or resources that you could point me to. Thanks!

Comment: Is `del result[:]` really necessary?

Comment: @cricket_007 you would need `result = []` inside the loop, though a simple list comp would do the same `result = [randint(0, 75) for _ in xrange(5)]`

Comment: @AChampion Right, but is reassignment less taxing than `del`? I would think so

Comment: @cricket_007 indeed, I would imagine so.

Comment: In my somewhat limited experience, 10mil loops will just take a long time.

Comment: I don't think PyCUDA would add much, looks like you just need to distribute the workload across multiple processors / servers if you need that many simulations. Does order matter for the wins? Can you get the same number twice? You may want to look at `random.sample()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lottery math is kind of odd;

First, `random.randint(0, 75)` generates values that include both endpoints - so you are picking from 76 values (0 .. 75). Maybe you meant `(1, 75)`?

Second, you are allowing repeated values, ie `3, 3, 3, 3, 3` is a valid ticket. Lotteries generally do not allow repeats. Take a look at `random.sample`, ie `random.sample(range(1, 76), 5)`

Third, the order in which you pick values apparently matters - `1, 2, 3, 4, 5` is different than `1, 3, 2, 4, 5`. Lotteries generally do not consider the order (except for possibly a bonus number). In Python terms, you should be comparing sets instead of lists.

Fourth, actually generating lists of values involves a lot of allocating and deallocating memory; you could get the same effect more cheaply by operating on enumerations of states rather than actually generating each state. For example, you could say that `{1, 4, 7, 19, 21}` is the millionth-and-third combination, then test `randvalue == 1000003` instead of `randset == {1, 4, 7, 19, 21}`.

Implementing these changes, you could simplify your logic like

```
from random import randrange
from math import factorial

VALUES = 75
PICKS = 5
TICKETS = 10000000

# calculate number of unique tickets
num_combos = factorial(VALUES) // (factorial(VALUES - PICKS) * factorial(PICKS))

winner = randrange(num_combos)
num_winners = sum(randrange(num_combos) == winner for _ in range(TICKETS))
```

**Edit:** had a quick thought and tested it;

```
num_winners = sum(1 for _ in range(TICKETS) if randrange(num_combos) == winner)
```

is about 5% faster. (More than 85% of runtime is now spent just generating random values.)

**Edit2:** another thought - if we arbitrarily say "0 is the winning state", then our main loop becomes

```
num_winners = sum(1 for _ in range(TICKETS) if not randrange(num_combos))
```

which speeds it up by another 2.5%.

---

Alternatively you could just go directly to the final solution,

```
from numpy.random import poisson

num_winners = poisson(TICKETS / num_combos)
```